# Angular2 ng-template documentation and usage

Tags: angular

I updated my project to the latest angular2 4.0.0-rc.5 and upon building it spits a lot of warnings like this:

```
Template parse warnings:
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("_newGroupReward.group.description}}
```

My question is - what is  and where can I find info about it and how to use it ? I have been googling however the only doc I could find is about the stable 2.4.x versions ( [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/) ).

Best regards

Answer (score 10):

**ngTemplate** is a replacement for template, It is used when a sample template should be injected into the DOM.

The below example is illustrated with using `ngIf else` as below,

```
<ng-template #loading>Failed to do something wrong...</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="userObservable;else loading;">
  Aravind is here
</div>
```

When I am using loading, angular calls the TemplateRef with the name as `loading` denoted by `#loading` and respective template is replaced inside the div.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bTk67K2MtRZluw8KCFGj)**

**[Documentation link](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/bf8eb41)**

Answer (score 6):

I found this reference. It may be helpful.

https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngfor-template-element

**Update:**

I was having the same issue. I fixed it by replacing the ng-template with ng-container . Take a look to the official [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ng-container) for more details.